# Disable weekdays and holidays in jQuery datepicker issue in WooCommerce

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, woocommerce, datepicker

I have a custom woocommerce filter function which use the **jQuery-ui datepicker**. I would like to customize the options with the code below but it just make the datepicker disappear, even when I try to enqueue the script. This code is customized from this answer:

[Can the jQuery UI Datepicker be made to disable Saturdays and Sundays (and holidays)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/501943/can-the-jquery-ui-datepicker-be-made-to-disable-saturdays-and-sundays-and-holid/503082#503082)

Below is the code for the delivery-date.js that I enqueue in my php also below.

```js
  /*====================================================
      Delivery date Code
      Only two weeks booking time allowed.
      Diallowed days Sunday = 0, Saturday = 6
    Dates Disallowed by m/d - 1,1 | 1,26 | 2,16 | 3,8 | 4,14 | 4, 16 | 4,17 | 5,1 | 6,3 | 6,9 | 10,9 | 12,25 | 12, 26
  =====================================================*/
  jQuery(function($){ 
      $('#datepicker').datepicker({
      maxDate: '+2W', 
      beforeShowDay: noWeekendsOrHolidays
    }); 

    var natDays = [ [1,1], [1,26], [2,16], [3,8], [4,14], [4, 16], [4,17], [5,1], [6,3], [6,9], [10,9], [12,25], [12, 26] ];

    function nationalDays(date) {
      for (i = 0; i < natDays.length; i++){
        if (date.getMonth() == natDays[i][0] - 1
          && date.getDate() == natDays[i][1]) {
          return [false, natDays[i][2] + '_day'];
        }
      }
      return [true, ''];
    }

    function noWeekendsOrHolidays(date) {
      var noWeekend = $.datepicker.noWeekends(date);
      if (noWeekend[0]) {
        return nationalDays(date);
      } else {
        return noWeekend;
      }
    }
  });
```

I am trying to merge that in this answer code: 
[Time loop for WooCommerce checkout select option from date picker input field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48443751/time-loop-for-woocommerce-checkout-select-option-from-date-picker-input-field/48454475#48454475)

But it doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your array is quiet different than the one used in: 
[Can the jQuery UI Datepicker be made to disable Saturdays and Sundays (and holidays)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/501943/can-the-jquery-ui-datepicker-be-made-to-disable-saturdays-and-sundays-and-holid/503082#503082)

To make it work with your custom array in Wordpress / Woocommerce you will need to make some changes. In the below code, I have merged the 2 Javascript functions in one:

```js
jQuery(function($){
    var natDays = [ [1,1], [1,26], [2,16], [3,8], [4,14], [4, 16],
        [4,17], [5,1], [6,3], [6,9], [10,9], [12,25], [12, 26] ]; // Holidays

    // No weekends and no holidays
    function noWeekendAndHolidays(date) {
        // No Holidays
        var nationalDays = [];
        for (i = 0; i < natDays.length; i++)
            if (date.getMonth() == natDays[i][0] - 1 && date.getDate() == natDays[i][1]) {
                nationalDays = [false, ''];
                return false; // stop the loop
            }
        if( ! nationalDays[0] )
            nationalDays = [true, ''];

        // No weekends (or no holidays)
        var noWeekend = $.datepicker.noWeekends(date);
        if (noWeekend[0])
            return nationalDays;
        else
            return noWeekend;
    }

    // Jquery-ui datepicker
    $("#datepicker").datepicker({
        beforeShowDay: noWeekendAndHolidays,
        maxDate: '+2W',
    });
});
```

This just works now with your custom array and the **jQuery-ui datepicker** is displayed correctly.

---

To merge it in [my other answer code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48443751/time-loop-for-woocommerce-checkout-select-option-from-date-picker-input-field/48454475#48454475) you will have it this way:

```
 // Enable available jQuery datepicker script in Wordpress
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'enabling_date_picker' );
function enabling_date_picker() {

    // Only on front-end and checkout page
    if( is_admin() || ! is_checkout() ) return;

    // Load available datepicker jQuery-ui plugin script
    wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery-ui-datepicker' );
}

// Add and display custom checkout fields + jQuery script
add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_fields' , 'brown_remove_billing_postcode_checkout' );
function brown_remove_billing_postcode_checkout( $fields ) {
    // Your Settings
    $start_hour = 11; // start time (in hours)
    $end_hour = 16; // end time (in hours)
    $offset = 1; // One hour before slot time (can be a float number like 1.5
    // date_default_timezone_set ('Africa/Kampala'); // The timezone
    date_default_timezone_set('Australia/Brisbane');

    // Initializing variables
    $hour = 3600; // 1 hour in seconds
    $day = $hour * 24; // 1 day in seconds
    $now = strtotime("now"); // Now time
    $real_now = $now + ($offset * $hour); // Now time + offset
    $today_date = date("Y-m-d"); // today date
    $tomorrow_date = date("Y-m-d", strtotime("+1 day")); // tomorow date
    $today_time = strtotime($today_date); // Today time at 00:00 in seconds
    $tomorrow_time = strtotime($tomorrow_date); // Tomorrow time at 00:00 in seconds
    $start_time = $today_time + ( $start_hour * $hour ); // Start datetime in seconds
    $end_time = $today_time + ( $end_hour * $hour ); // End datetime in seconds
    $today_slots = $default_slots = $option_days = array();

    // Add Delivery day field (with jquery-ui datepicker enabled)
    $fields['billing']['billing_delivery_day'] = array(
        'label'         => __('Delivery Day', 'woocommerce'),
        'placeholder'   => _x('Date for your delivery', 'placeholder', 'woocommerce'),
        'required'      => true,
        'id'            => 'datepicker', // Enable jQuery datepicker for this field
        'class'         => array('form-row-first'),
        'clear'         => false,
        'autocomplete'  => false,
        'type'          => 'text'
    );
   // Add Delivery hour slots
    $fields['billing']['billing_delivery_hour'] = array(
        'label'        => __('Delivery Time', 'woocommerce'),
        'required'     => true,
        'class'        => array('form-row-last'),
        'clear'        => false,
        'autocomplete' => false,
        'type'         => 'select',
        'options'      => array( '' => __('Select time for your delivery') ),
    );

    // Making the delivery hour slots <option> arrays for Javascript
    for($i = $start_time; $i <= $end_time; $i += 1800 ){ // 1800 seconds is half an hour
        $key     = date('H:i', $i);
        $value   = date('h:ia', $i);

        // Today available hour slots array
        if($real_now < $i)
            $today_slots[$key] = $value;

        // Default hour slots array
        $default_slots[$key] = $value;
    }

    // The correct start date and time (today or tomorow) for Javascript
    $date = $real_now < $end_time ? $today_date : $tomorrow_date;
    $dtime = $real_now < $end_time ? date("Y-m-d\TH:i:s", $today_time) : date("Y-m-d\TH:i:s", $tomorrow_time);

    ?>
    <script>
        jQuery(function($){
            var offsetDate = 14, // Number of days enabled in the date picker
                startingDate = new Date('<?php echo $dtime; ?>'), // Starting day
                endingDate = new Date('<?php echo $dtime; ?>'), // End date is calculated below
                todaySlots = <?php echo json_encode($today_slots); ?>,
                defaultSlots = <?php echo json_encode($default_slots); ?>,
                sDay = 'input[name ="billing_delivery_day"]',
                sHour = 'select[name ="billing_delivery_hour"]',
                defaultOption = $(sHour+' > option').text(),
                todaySlotsLength = Object.keys(todaySlots).length,
                natDays = [ [1,1], [1,26], [2,16], [3,8], [4,14], [4, 16],
                [4,17], [5,1], [6,3], [6,9], [10,9], [12,25], [12, 26] ]; // Holidays

            // ------ 1). Dates and Date picker ------ //

            // Set the default field start date
            $(sDay).val('<?php echo $date; ?>');
            $('#datepicker_field').addClass('woocommerce-validated');

            // Max date calculation
            endingDate.setDate(startingDate.getDate()+offsetDate);
            console.log(new Date($(sDay).val()));

            // No weekends and no holidays
            function noWeekendAndHolidays(date) {
                // No Holidays
                var nationalDays = [];
                for (i = 0; i < natDays.length; i++)
                    if (date.getMonth() == natDays[i][0] - 1 && date.getDate() == natDays[i][1]) {
                        nationalDays = [false, ''];
                        return false; // stop the loop
                    }
                if( ! nationalDays[0] )
                    nationalDays = [true, ''];

                // No weekends (or no holidays)
                var noWeekend = $.datepicker.noWeekends(date);
                if (noWeekend[0])
                    return nationalDays;
                else
                    return noWeekend;
            }

            // Jquery-ui datepicker
            $("#datepicker").datepicker({
                beforeShowDay: noWeekendAndHolidays,
                dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd",
                minDate: startingDate,
                maxDate: endingDate, // optional
                setDate: startingDate,
            });

            // ------ 2). HOUR slots select field (dynamic <option>) ------ //

            // Build the <option> html html in the select field dynamically
            function dynamic_select_options_buid( slotsType ){
                $.each( slotsType, function( index, value ){
                    $(sHour).append('<option value="'+index+'">'+value+'</option>');
                });
            }
            // Replace and Build the <option> html in the select field dynamically
            function dynamic_select_options_replace( slotsType ){
                $(sHour+' > option').remove();
                $(sHour).append('<option value="">'+defaultOption+'</option>');
                dynamic_select_options_buid( slotsType );
            }

            console.log(defaultOption);
            console.log(todaySlotsLength);
            if(todaySlotsLength != 0 && todaySlotsLength < 11 ){
                // Loaded at start
                dynamic_select_options_buid( todaySlots );

                // Live date selection event
                $(sDay).change( function(){
                    console.log('day changed: '+$(this).val());
                    if( $(this).val() != '<?php echo $date; ?>' )
                        dynamic_select_options_replace( defaultSlots );
                    else
                        dynamic_select_options_replace( todaySlots );
                })
            } else {
                dynamic_select_options_buid( defaultSlots );
            }
        });
    </script>
    <?
    return $fields;
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme).

Tested and works.